# MongoDB Count Query Optimization

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

I have total 1644662 records in one of my collections, I have created index on one of my column named "document_type_id". When I run a query

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({"document_type_id": {"$in": ["7"]}}).count()
```

It returns count "753800" in 0.285 secs. And When I run a query

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({"document_type_id": {"$in": ["3"]}}).count()
```

It returns count "819438" in 0.365 secs. Both queries working perfect. But problem comes when I run query by combining both

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({"document_type_id": {"$in": ["3", "7"]}}).count()
```

This query takes 54 secs to return the count. Execution Plan for third query is as follows:

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "test.my_collection",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "document_type_id" : {
            "$in" : [ 
                "3", 
                "7"
            ]
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COUNT",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "document_type_id" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "document_type_id_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "document_type_id" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "document_type_id" : [ 
                        "[\"3\", \"3\"]", 
                        "[\"7\", \"7\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 0,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 74166,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 1573238,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 1573238,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "COUNT",
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 73504,
        "works" : 1573239,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 1573238,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 14007,
        "restoreState" : 14007,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "nCounted" : 1573238,
        "nSkipped" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "nReturned" : 1573238,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 73253,
            "works" : 1573239,
            "advanced" : 1573238,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 14007,
            "restoreState" : 14007,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 1573238,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 1573238,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2729,
                "works" : 1573239,
                "advanced" : 1573238,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 14007,
                "restoreState" : 14007,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "document_type_id" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "document_type_id_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "document_type_id" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "document_type_id" : [ 
                        "[\"3\", \"3\"]", 
                        "[\"7\", \"7\"]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 1573238,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "nb-fara",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.4.9",
    "gitVersion" : "876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e"
},
"ok" : 1.0
```

}

Comment: 1) are the values of `document_type_id` numeric in string ? 2) you have FETCH stage in your explain output, what's your actual query that generated the explain ? 3) what's your MongoDB deployment topology ? standalone, replicaset or sharded cluster.

Comment: 1) yes 2)db.getCollection('my_collection').explain('executionStats').find({"document_type_id": {"$in": ["3", "7"]}}).count() 3) I'm testing on my local machine laptop.

Comment: 1) What is the size of your laptop memory ? 2) What is the average size of a document ? `Object.bsonsize(db. my_collection.findOne())`

Comment: 1) Laptop has 16GB RAM, 1TB harddisk. Size of a document is 339667, returned by Object.bsonsize.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
db.collection.count({...})
```

instead of

```
db.collection.find({...}).count()
```

because `count()` can directly take a query as parameter, see [**`db.collection.count()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) for details

So your query would be:

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').count({"document_type_id": {"$in": ["3", "7"]}})
```

Here is the explain of this query (finished in **~0.202s** on my machine with **MongoDB 3.6.2**):

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.test",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "document_type_id" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "3",
                    "7"
                ]
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "document_type_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "document_type_id_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "document_type_id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "document_type_id" : [
                        "[\"3\", \"3\"]",
                        "[\"7\", \"7\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 202,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 274112,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 170,
            "works" : 274112,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 274111,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 2141,
            "restoreState" : 2141,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "nCounted" : 274110,
            "nSkipped" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 274110,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 140,
                "works" : 274112,
                "advanced" : 274110,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 2141,
                "restoreState" : 2141,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "document_type_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "document_type_id_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "document_type_id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "document_type_id" : [
                        "[\"3\", \"3\"]",
                        "[\"7\", \"7\"]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 274112,
                "seeks" : 2,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "xxxxxxx",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.2",
        "gitVersion" : "489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But I got the 50 secs of execution time.

Comment: @fazalerabbi what version of mongodb are you using ?

Comment: Version is 3.4.9. You can also find in query explain.

Comment: What do you think, I need to update to version 3.6.2, or can you test this with 3.4.9?

Comment: @fazalerabbi just tested on Mongodb 3.4.2, query took ~0.5s... I guess there's something else going on here, but it's hard to know what exactly without the exact same data...

Comment: My each document has atleast 45 columns, and 5 are sub documents. Total documents are1644662. 15houndred thousand are documents having document type id 3 and 7. I m stuck in this query. Don't know how to make it fast ☺️

Comment: Can you please share the execution plan with version 3.4.9.

Comment: What document structure you have created for testing?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({"document_type_id": {"$or": ["3", "7"]}}).count()
```

Comment: This `$or`  will give you the same result and reduces the time to run the query

Comment: Thank you, But I am getting this error:

2018-01-20T12:50:31.673+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: count failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "unknown operator: $or",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
} :

Comment: That should be {"$or": [{"document_type_id": "3"}, {"document_type_id": "7"}]} - even if I really don't believe that that query is faster. Curious to see the results...

Comment: `{"$or": [{"document_type_id": "3"}, {"document_type_id": "7"}]}` yes this  is the format i just forgot.I hope this is better when compared with `$in`

Comment: It has same execution time (54 secs).

Comment: MongoDB documentation says: "When using $or with <expressions> that are equality checks for the value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or operator."
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Answer (score 0):

With  db version v3.0.7 getting below

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.test",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "document_type_id" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "3",
                    "7"
                ]
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "document_type_id" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            "3",
                            "7"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 681,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2000100,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 630,
            "works" : 2000102,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 2000101,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 15625,
            "restoreState" : 15625,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "nCounted" : 400020,
            "nSkipped" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "document_type_id" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            "3",
                            "7"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 400020,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 600,
                "works" : 2000101,
                "advanced" : 400020,
                "needTime" : 1600081,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 15625,
                "restoreState" : 15625,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "docsExamined" : 2000100
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ptpll354",
        "port" : 5000,
        "version" : "3.0.7",
        "gitVersion" : "6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can u try it out in a fresh mongod instance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the aggregate framework?

```
db.my_collection.aggregate( [
   { $project : { "document_type_id" : 1 }},
   { $match : { "document_type_id": { "$in": ["3", "7"] } } },
   { $group : { _id : '$document_type_id', count: { $sum: 1} } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MongoDb is using the Mulikey Index but is only using it to lookup the Min/Max bounds due to it being a `$in` query, you can read more here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/multikey-index-bounds/#intersect-bounds-for-multikey-index

Changing it to a `or` should work

```
db.my_collection.count({"$or": [{"document_type_id": "3"}, {"document_type_id": "7"}]})
```

Comment: Document type id isn't multiple key, it has single value, either 7 or 3